# Python execution environment: Modules listed in sys.modules

Tags: python, environment, execution, sys

In python language reference **9.1. Complete Python programs** it says: -

> A complete Python program is executed in a minimally initialized
> environment: all built-in and standard modules are available, but none
> have been initialized, except for sys (various system services),
> builtins (built-in functions, exceptions and None) and **main**.

But when I print `sys.modules` in any python program or in python REPL, I see many modules loaded in the program. So if the python program in executed in a minimally initialized environment then why do I see a huge list in `sys.modules` even if I am not importing any modules? What does the statement *none have been initialize* mean here?

Answer (score 0):

All the modules that you see when you print `sys.modules` before importing anything are the 'builtins' and system modules that are part of the python implementation and are always loaded.

The statement *none have been initialized* refers to all the standard modules included in python that you actually have to import to use them. You can see a list of them here: https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html

Comment: Still not clear. The reference says that the complete python program is run in a minimally initialized environment, none have been initialized except for sys, builtins and __main__. If that is the case then I should only be seeing these three in sys. modules.